# Can image meta data for creation date and original GPS location be pulled via API from services like Facebook, Instagram?

Tags: image, api, metadata

Can image meta data for creation date and original GPS location be pulled via API from services like Facebook, Instagram? Or is the original meta set re-written by the services after user upload so you get a filtered/reduced version via API? If so, any way to access the original meta data?

Comment: metadata is wiped on most social services. So no, you can't retrieve the original GPS location from those services.